# exibição de caracteres utilizando códigos numéricos: &#2039

Tags: html, html5, codificação-de-caracteres, ascii

Tentei pesquisar sobre o assunto no Google, mas foi difícil, pois vários outros assuntos estão relacionados, então pergunto aqui.

Estou utilizando caracteres especiais, impressos a partir do respectivo código numérico, em uma página: &#2039 = ߷

Mas alguns caracteres não são exibidos: &#1970 = ޲ (pra mim aparece um quadrado com números dentro)

Isso acontece com vários códigos numéricos.

As minhas dúvidas são:

1. Esse problema existe, pois o símbolo não existe para o número especificado ?
2. Isso tem relação com o idioma ? (obs: vários caracteres chineses, japoneses, indianos e outros aparecem normalmente)
3. É "problema meu", pois utilizo: "Windows 8.1 Pro PT-BR" + "Firefox 51" ?

Minha preocupação é a página depender de algum tipo de configuração, e o resultado ser diferente dependendo do usuário/sistema/browser/idioma.

Comment: Você adicionou no `head` *`<meta charset=”utf-8”>`*?

Comment: Sim. Só que "<meta charset='utf-8'>" é para a codificação do arquivo html, e não para exibição. Estou utilizando números para definir os símbolos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei as respostas das minhas dúvidas:

1. Esse problema existe, pois o símbolo não existe para o número especificado ?

   - Sim, alguns números não possuem caractere/símbolo
   - http://graphite.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?item_id=IWS-Chapter04a
   - > There are gaps in the Unicode codespace....
2. Isso tem relação com o idioma ?

   - Não, tem relação com o Unicode
   - http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode4.0.0/ch01.pdf
3. É "problema meu"... ?

   - Sim, alguns caracteres precisam de configuração e fontes de texto específicas
   - http://unicode.org/help/display_problems.html

Pra terminar: [Failures to display a character](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars.html#display)

Answer (score 2):

Só complementando:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Issues_related_to_fonts

> This article describes issues caused by missing font support and missing or corrupted fonts and other issues where websites do not display properly like text that overlaps or you see gibberish or diamonds with a '?' or boxes with hex code.

http://utf8everywhere.org/

> Our goal is to promote usage and support of the UTF-8 encoding and to convince that it should be the default choice of encoding for storing text strings in memory or on disk, for communication and all other uses.
>   Many third-party libraries for Windows do not support Unicode: they accept narrow string parameters and pass them to the ANSI API